# How to start command on boot in Fedora 26 to reverse scroll mouse?

Tags: fedora, systemd, startup, xinput

I am trying to start the following command on boot "xinput set-prop 13 289 1"

I created a systemd service called reversemouse.service

When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
[brandon@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status reversemouse.service 
● reversemouse.service - Description of the systemd service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/reversemouse.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-07-17 21:11:51 EDT; 4s ago
  Process: 2863 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c xinput set-prop 13 289 1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2863 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 17 21:11:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Description of the systemd service...
Jul 17 21:11:51 localhost.localdomain sh[2863]: Unable to connect to X server
Jul 17 21:11:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: reversemouse.service: Main process exited, code=exited, sta
Jul 17 21:11:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Description of the systemd service.
Jul 17 21:11:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: reversemouse.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 17 21:11:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: reversemouse.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Do you know what this error means, did I format the systemd service correctly? Here is my systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description of the systemd service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "xinput set-prop 13 289 1"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: You want a --user service: system services know nothing about your individual session. Better still, put it in your `.xinitrc`.

Comment: How would I add it to .xinitrc? Thanks!

Comment: The same way you put it in a service file: `xinput blah blah blah`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by creating a desktop application:

In ~/.config/autostart, create a desktop file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=startup
GenericName=startup
Comment=Start these up at login
Exec=/home/[your username]/reversemouse.sh
Terminal=False
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Then copied copied desktop file to autostart folder: /usr/share/applications/ to ~/.config/autostart/

Lastly, I made a startup file with the command I wanted to run (reversemouse.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

xinput set-prop 13 289 1
```